# Neat way to prove $\sin(\alpha+\beta)$ using complex exponential

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I am supposed to prove that $\sin(\alpha+\beta)=\sin\alpha\cos\beta+\sin\beta\cos\alpha$ using complex exponentials:

$$
\begin{align}
\sin\theta&=-\frac{1}{2}i(e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta})\\
\cos\theta&=\frac{1}{2}(e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta})
\end{align}
$$

The proof that I have done is very long and messy and essentially I am showing that LHS and RHS are the same thing. I was wondering if there is a neater proof?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**

Take the imaginary part of
$$e^{i(\alpha+\beta)}=e^{i\alpha}e^{i\beta}$$

Comment: Can't get more succinct than that! You are great at saying what needs to be said very succinctly!

Comment: Thanks dear amWhy but If I improve my English I would give longer answers;-)

Comment: You actually have a pretty "darn" good mastery of English, Sami! Seriously.